# What is the data type of the onClickListenerObj field in the below code?

Tags: java, android, types, interface, event-listener

```
        View.OnClickListener onClickListenerObj = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //some logic.
        }
    };
```

In the above code, what is the type (data type) of the onClickListnerObj? Since the onClickListener is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated what is the type of the onClicListenerObj field. Is it view or something else and for what is the new keyword used and is the onClickListener the constructor of view class?

Answer (score 1):

The type of `onClickListenerObj` is `View.OnClickListener`, which means there is a class named `View` and it has a member called `OnClickListener`. And onClickListenerObj is an instance of `OnClickListener`.